# How can I convince OneDrive that it should use a folder on my SD-Card?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I've just upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1 on my Microsoft Surface Pro.   OneDrive is telling me it cannot use the current location I had configured in Windows 8.1, which was located on my 128GB SD-card.

I've tried the usual suspects with the mklink command-line utility to create a symbolic directory link from C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive to D:\OneDrive like:

```
mklink /d C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive D:\OneDrive
```

and

```
mklink /j C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive D:\OneDrive
```

and even:

```
mklink /j C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive2 D:\OneDrive
mklink /d C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive2
```

Nothing works.  When I open OneDrive, it asks me for the location of my OneDrive folder, which I the point to `C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive`, however, it keeps saying:

> Your OneDrive folder can't be created in the location you selected.

I'm now in the middle of creating a `.VHDX` on the SD-Card, and mounting that in `C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive`, which I presume will work; however is there a nicer way?  Perhaps some registry tweak?  Perhaps a big hammer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of today this is now officially supported. Simply pick the removable drive you want to use.

https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/6449138-allow-onedrive-to-sync-to-removable-media-on-windo

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use SD card by mounting it to c:\sd using `diskmgmt.msc`

The dialog to select the folders will still however think that you have as much space as c:, so add the data in parts to fool it.