# Is it possible to get OneDrive to use a SDXC card for its local folder, specifically in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

Is it possible to get OneDrive to use a SDXC card for its local folder, specifically in Windows 10?

I had OneDrive working fine on my Surface Pro 3 using a SanDisk SDXC card when it was Windows 8.1

But after the upgrade to Windows 10, OneDrive won't accept the SDXC card D:\ drive for its target, only the internal disk C:\ drive

Comment: Yes it is possible. [See this superuser question/answer](http://superuser.com/questions/952521).